# How to dynamically display a number of input fields based on a number given on a previous field on that page in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I just started using React.js and I have some questions. I want to make a page for a quiz test for the app that I am working on. On this page, the user should provide info about the quiz, including the number of questions. On entering the number of questions an equal number of input fields should then also be displayed. Can someone help me, please?

```
return(
        <div className="col-md-12">
            <div>
               <p>Add a new quiz for {courseTitle} course!</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="numberOfQuestions">Number Of Questions: </label>
                <input type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        name="numberOfQuestions"
                        value={numberOfQuestions}
                        onChange={onChangeNumberOfQuestions}    
                        validations={[required, validNumber]}
                />
            </div>
            <Form>
            {questions &&( 
                <div>
                    {addQuestion()}
                </div>
            )
            }
            </Form>

        </div>
    );
```

Here is what I have in return. The user gives a number and by that value should be displayed that number of input fields.

```
function addQuestion (){
        return (
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="numberOfQuestions"> Question {+1} </label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    name="question"
                    //value={question}
                    //onChange={onChangeFirstName}
                    //validations={[required, validFirstName]}
                />
            </div>              
        );
    }
```

Intially a tried using a for loop in this function and for every value of `i` to return that input field but it didn't work.

```
const AddQuiz = () =>{
    const location = useLocation();
    console.log(location.state);
    const {courseTitle, courseYear, userId, courseId} = location.state;
    const[numberOfQuestions, setNumberOfQuestions] = useState(0);
    const[questions, setQuestions] = useState(false);
    const question = [];
    const answear = [];
    
    const onChangeNumberOfQuestions = (e) => {
        const numberOfQuestions = e.target.value;
        setNumberOfQuestions(numberOfQuestions);
        if(numberOfQuestions > 0){
            setQuestions(true);
        }
    };

    function addQuestion (){
        return (
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="numberOfQuestions"> Question {+1} </label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    name="question"
                    //value={question}
                    //onChange={onChangeQuestion}
                    //validations={[required, validQuestion]}
                />
            </div>              
        );
    }
   
    console.log(numberOfQuestions);
    console.log(questions);

    return(
        <div className="col-md-12">
            <div>
               <p>Add a new quiz for {courseTitle} course!</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="numberOfQuestions">Number Of Questions: </label>
                <input type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        name="numberOfQuestions"
                        value={numberOfQuestions}
                        onChange={onChangeNumberOfQuestions}    
                        validations={[required, validNumber]}
                />
            </div>
            <Form>
            {questions &&( 
                <div>
                    {addQuestion()}
                </div>
            )
            }
            </Form>

        </div>
    );
};


export default AddQuiz;
```

And this is my arrow function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recreated the logic that you have asked for.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-aruf3f?file=src%2FApp.js) - Click this link to see the output.

This is just a gist you can expand the code by handling errors also. That'll good for your learning.

```
    const onChangeNumberOfQuestions = (e) => {
        const numberOfQuestions = e.target.value;
        
        setNumberOfQuestions(numberOfQuestions);
        if(numberOfQuestions > 0){
          const generateArrays= Array.from(Array(Number(e.target.value)).keys())
            setQuestions(generateArrays);
        } else {
          setQuestions([])
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I use a similar concept for the answer field for this questions?

Comment: Can you upvote the answer? If it suits the best!

Comment: Yes you can do it!

Comment: And do you have any ideea how to add the content from each field (each question field) to an array? I want to give different inputs in each question field but everytime I try to write in one question field, that data will appear in other input fields.

Answer (score 0):

**Apparently, this cannot be done without using Arrays/Objects. So, I'm storing the string inside the Array, and that number of input fields will be created dynamically.**

```
import { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  const setNumberOfInput = (count) => {
    setNumber(count);
  };
  const fields = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    fields.push("Enter question: "+i);
  }
 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="number" onChange={(e) => setNumberOfInput(e.target.value)} />
      <br/>
      {fields.map((str) => {
        return(
          <>
            <span>{str}</span>
            <input/>
            <br/>
          </>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-react-question-1-k6rzj) link for the same. The code is working here.

Note: **I'm not an expert in React, but this is what I came up with after searching about the same. This code works and might help you :-)**